# How to reload dataTables on ajax and trigger new paginations

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatables

First of, I used the javascript example here, I grasp the basic and altered it on my own.

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

I have a couple of problems to deal with, those are:

1. Once the datatable load on page load, it successfully retrieves the default data BUT it doesn't apply the proper pagination and length view. Say I have 100 default data, it all fully shown, rather than slicing it by 10 which is the default length of dataTable. Also in pagination, it generates 1~10 paginating buttons but it doesn't work since all 100 records are already displayed in page 1.
2. Upon using the search, it successfully retrieves the correct data BUT the dataTable doesn't render the newly set of data to it, contradicting to the sample above.

This is my dataTable script:

```
    $('#invoice-history').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        searchDelay: 1000,
        ajax: {
            url: '/stock-sales/search',
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { data: 'ss_id' },
            {
                render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                    return  row.patient_last_name + ', ' + row.patient_first_name;
                }
            },
            { data: 'grandtotal_current' },
            { data: 'created_at' },
            {
                render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                    return  '<a href="/reports/invoice/' + row.ss_id + '/print" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-block"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print</a>';
                }
            },
            {
                render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                    return  '<a href="/stock-sales/return/' + row.ss_id + '" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-block"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i> Return</a>';
                }
            }
        ],
        columnDefs: [ {
              targets: [ 4, 5 ],
              orderable: false
        } ],
        language: {
            emptyTable: '<center><span class="label label-danger">NO INVOICE RECORDS FOUND</span></center>',
            zeroRecords: '<center><span class="label label-danger">NO MATCHING RECORDS FOUND</span></center>'
        },
        order: [[ 3, 'desc' ]]
    });
```

On the server-side I use Laravel framework:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $transactions = StockSales::getAllByDepartment(Auth::user()->employee->department->id, $request->search['value']);

    return array(
        "draw" => 1,
        "recordsTotal" => count($transactions),
        "recordsFiltered" => count($transactions),
        "data" => $transactions
    );
}
```

I don't want to get the original total number of records before filter so I set it the same, I don't think it has something to do with pagination of the resulting data as I have also tried to hardcoded a higher recordsTotal value.

EDIT:

actually made the searching redraw the datatable by returning the draw interger from the ajax

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $transactions = StockSales::getAllByDepartment(Auth::user()->employee->department->id, $request->search['value']);

    return array(
        "draw" => $request->draw, //from fixed 1
        "recordsTotal" => count($transactions),
        "recordsFiltered" => count($transactions),
        "data" => $transactions
    );
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try the "pageLength"  attribute in your datatable initialization to specify the number of rows per page.

```
"pageLength": 10,
```

Server side:
You need to use the 'length' and 'start' parameters passed by the ajax request for server-side pagination. Take a look at all the [parameters](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) used by datatables in server-side processing.

```
$limit = $request->length;
$start = $request->start;
```

Thus, you can fine-tune your controller method to something like:

```
$transactions = StockSales::getAllByDepartment(Auth::user()->employee->department->id,
        $request->search['value'])
        ->offset($start)
        ->limit($limit);

return array(
    "draw" => $request->draw, //from fixed 1
    "recordsTotal" => count($transactions),
    "recordsFiltered" => count($transactions),
    "data" => $transactions
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is you misunderstood about server side processing `serverSide: true` Due to https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

> With server-side processing enabled, all paging, searching, ordering actions that DataTables performs are handed off to a server where an SQL engine (or similar) can perform these actions on the large data set (after all, that's what the database engine is designed for!). As such, each draw of the table will result in a new Ajax request being made to get the required data.

In your case you return all data on ajax called and think datatable will process pagination, ordering for you. That is wrong, you must do it by yourself on ajax called

However, 100 records are not large and you can fix your problem by

```
    serverSide: false
```

Change like that, datatable will load all data from ajax source and process for you

Comment: I have actually a million records, i only default 100 and let the datable search do the retrieving of other data

Comment: `$request->search['value']` this value you get from datatable filter ? If not just change `serverSide: false` it may work as you want

Comment: I manage to make the searching work by actually returning the draw value that is sent to me by the ajax, problem now is its still rendering all result in page 1